# How to use ng-repeat over multiple div elements?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to achieve the following (which does not work as written):

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.headline}}</div>
<div>{{product.text}}</div>
```

I only first see all headlines, then all texts below each other. How can refer to product again on an additional div element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nifty feature in Angular whereby some directives, like `ng-repeat`, support spanning across multiple elements:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="product in products">{{product.headline}}</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>{{product.text}}</div>
```

You can also create custom directives that support this functionality. Here's a snippet from [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-):

> `multiElement`
>
> When this property is set to true, the HTML compiler will collect DOM nodes between nodes with the attributes `directive-name-start` and `directive-name-end`, and group them together as the directive elements. It is recommended that this feature be used on directives which are not strictly behavioural (such as `ngClick`), and which do not manipulate or replace child nodes (such as `ngInclude`).

Comment: Amazing, that's really great.